# However Outlook is accessible, I can't access to Gmail via Nexus 4

Tags: updates, gmail, nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat

despite I can access to internet network through chrome browser and check my email by using "Outlook" application by Microsoft Corporation, I have not had my "gmail", "google+" since December 17th. I have not succeeded to check update since December 17th. My cellphone is Nexus 4 and its OS is Android 4.4.2.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Could you please prove a bit more background: What have your tried? Were there any errors, and if so, what exactly are the error messages? If you go to quick settings, what color are your network indicators? Can you access *Google Play*?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consideration, I upgraded my phone operation system to 4.2.2 android version on December 15, but I haven't accessed to all Google services (exception to Chrome) by using cellphone. Also it hasn't allowed me to check system update status since December 17. I haven't seen any error message. Color of network indicators is orange as same as one that had before December 17. I live in Iran, where Google Play doesn't permit us to access it legally.

Comment: OK, the orange color stands for "cannot reach Google servers" (so you know why there are no updates). As it seems other apps can access the net normally, it's no "general network issue". As you indicate "censorship": could it be Google servers are blocked by some (national) firewall? Though that would be a strange co-incidence, starting right after the update. Could you try accessing some Google pages (e.g. Playstore) via browser? I'm not sure what servers (IP ranges) are required by Google services, or I'd recommend a ping-test to those.

Comment: My gadget stared working by itself. It was ridiculous error that confused me. Firewall might have caused this problem.

Comment: Glad it solved! You might wish to make that an answer, and accept it later (the latter you can do about 2 days after posting it).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has happened after a recent update to your nexus 4 to the latest kitkat update?
How did you do this update, was it naturally from google or did you manually force the update by clearing your google services framework cache? I have seen this happen before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consideration, I upgraded my phone operation system to 4.2.2 android version on December 15, but I haven't accessed to all Google services (exception to Chrome) by using cellphone. Also it hasn't allowed me to check system update status since December 17. I received upgrading file from Google's servers through WiFi network(OTA method)that didn't make phone to clear Google services framework caches for updating system